# use \eqref or \ref for an equation inside flalign and aligned

Tags: equations

I need to have an equation aligned on the left of my page and its tag on the right.
I managed to do it but when i want to call it with \eqref or \ref it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}\tag{1.8}
&\begin{aligned}{}
\label{eq:1.8}
x(t)=e^{-\left|a\cdot t\right|}  \\
\end{aligned}&&
\end{flalign*}

\noindent With the equation \ref{eq:1.8} ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is nothing to label when the numbering env is starred (flalign*). So what exactly is it you want? Does using `flalign` without the `*` help?

Comment: you are using two (!!) alignment structures, aligned inside flalign, but you have a one line equation with therefore no alignment possible. Also do you really need to number the equation by hand in this way?

Comment: I want to call the equation with \ref or \eqref or something similar.
If i don't number the equation with \tag i obtain only "8" and not "1.8"

Comment: No the formatting of automatically numbered equations can use section . equation format if that is what you want,  but a one line equation should be using `equation` not and alignment structure, and certainly not nested alignment structures with no alignment

Comment: Regardless of other comments (which are valid), if you have `\tag{1.8}` you should have `\ref{1.8}`, *not* `\ref{eq:1.8}`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have any alignment here so I used `equation` and it is usually better to let latex number the equations automatically, so I specified numbering within sections:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
\section{Intro}

\setcounter{equation}{7}% just in this example

Using equation
\begin{equation}\label{eq:xt}
x(t)=e^{-\lvert a\cdot t\rvert} 
\end{equation}
With the equation \ref{eq:xt} (avoid numbers in labels)

\end{document}
```

or left aligned

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,fleqn]{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 

\usepackage{mathtools}
\setlength\mathindent{0pt}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }

\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\begin{document}
\section{Intro}

\setcounter{equation}{7}% just in this example

Using equation
\begin{equation}\label{eq:xt}
x(t)=e^{-\lvert a\cdot t\rvert} 
\end{equation}
With the equation \ref{eq:xt} (avoid numbers in labels)

\end{document}
```

Comment: as I said i need the equation to be on the left of my page that's why i use flalign and aligned.. with equation it's always centered or not completely on the left

Comment: `\documentclass[fleqn]{article}` will give left aligned equations.

Comment: yes that's what i said, it isn't completely on the left if i use fleqn.. I need it to be more on the left like the rest of the text and I how to put the [11pt] with [fleqn] ?

Comment: `[11pt,fleqn]`  I added a left aligned version to the answer above @Hailey

Comment: Thank you very much, but with your code i still can't click on the equation number. It is like \ref doesn't work :/ 
Can you ?

Comment: @Hailey  `\ref` generates the number, it doesn't by default, make a link. To make such active links add `\usepackage{hyperref}`

Comment: Great !! thank you :))